# Pendulum on cart

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, acceleration, potential, harmonic-oscillator

We set a mathematical pendulum on a cart that can move without friction horizontally in the direction of motion of the pendulum. The cart has an overall mass M. This mass will also include the pendulum frame which is considered to be a part of the cart. The pendulum comprises of a mass m
that moves on an arm of length ℓ. We choose the coordinates such that the fulcrum of the pendulum is located at

(
x
(
t
)
,
0
)


(
x
(
t
)
,
0
)
and the mass of the pendulum at 
(
x
+
ℓ
sin
⁡
θ
,
−
ℓ
cos
⁡
θ
)
 [image]

Taking Euler-Lagrange equation for Theta with respect to Center of Mass of system (i.e, COM is the referene point) will give this equation of motion (which was non-dimentionalized with time )

[image]

where 
μ
=
m

/

(
M
+
m
)

Now my question is about the accelration of center of mass as the pendulum swings while the cart is moving. if both m and M are relatively close in value,shouldn't the cart start to move back and forth as the pendulum swings?.Moreover, will there be a displacement along the x-axis for the cart so that the Center of Mass will not accelerate in x-direction?.

Also, in regard of the y-axis (vertical) component of center of mass, will it accelerate and starts to go up and down as the cart moves while the pendulum is swinging?.

Comment: I don’t think your equation is correct, where is the gravitation g ? Can you add the equation for x

Comment: The center of mass accelerations $a_x=0,a_y=-g$